# Expanding function based on array length

Tags: python, arrays, python-itertools

I have the following code, which I would like to make responsive to the initial array that is passed to it (letters). Currently it can handle letters <= 3, however I would like to make it expandable to n.

In this example, if the array only contains two entries ["a", " b"], it would trigger the second if statement.

How can I change this to have effectively infinite if statements, allowing an array of any size?

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

#variable length
letters = ["a", " b", " c"]

increment = .1
d = 3
e = 3

#Calculate total possible combinations and create array
x=0
for p in itertools.product(range(d), repeat=e):
    x = x+1

variable = np.arange(x)
variable_s = [str(x) for x in variable]


x=0
#run loop based on array length.
for p in itertools.product(range(d), repeat=e):
    if len(letters) == 1:
        variable_s[x] = letters[0]+str(format(p[0]/(increment)**(-1.0),'.2f')).replace("0.", "")
    elif len(letters) == 2:
        variable_s[x] = (
            letters[0]+str(format(p[0]/(increment)**(-1.0),'.2f')).replace("0.", "")
           +letters[1]+str(format(p[1]/(increment)**(-1.0),'.2f')).replace("0.", "")
        )
    elif len(letters) == 3:
        variable_s[x] = (
            letters[0]+str(format(p[0]/(increment)**(-1.0),'.2f')).replace("0.", "")
           +letters[1]+str(format(p[1]/(increment)**(-1.0),'.2f')).replace("0.", "")
           +letters[2]+str(format(p[2]/(increment)**(-1.0),'.2f')).replace("0.", "")
        )
    x = x+1
variable_s
```

The output from the code above would be: 
['a00 b00 c00',
 'a00 b00 c10',
 'a00 b00 c20',
 'a00 b10 c00',
 'a00 b10 c10',
 'a00 b10 c20',
 'a00 b20 c00',
 'a00 b20 c10',
 'a00 b20 c20',
 'a10 b00 c00',
 'a10 b00 c10',
 'a10 b00 c20',
 'a10 b10 c00',
 'a10 b10 c10',
 'a10 b10 c20',
 'a10 b20 c00',
 'a10 b20 c10',
 'a10 b20 c20',
 'a20 b00 c00',
 'a20 b00 c10',
 'a20 b00 c20',
 'a20 b10 c00',
 'a20 b10 c10',
 'a20 b10 c20',
 'a20 b20 c00',
 'a20 b20 c10',
 'a20 b20 c20']

If letters = ["a", "b"]  the output would be :
['a00 b00',
 'a00 b00',
 'a00 b00',
 'a00 b10',
 'a00 b10',
 'a00 b10',
 'a00 b20',
 'a00 b20',
 'a00 b20',
 'a10 b00',
 'a10 b00',
 'a10 b00',
 'a10 b10',
 'a10 b10',
 'a10 b10',
 'a10 b20',
 'a10 b20',
 'a10 b20',
 'a20 b00',
 'a20 b00',
 'a20 b00',
 'a20 b10',
 'a20 b10',
 'a20 b10',
 'a20 b20',
 'a20 b20',
 'a20 b20']

If letters ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] the output would be:
['a00 b00 c00 d00 e00 f00 g00',
 'a00 b00 c00 d00 e00 f00 g10',... etc.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Why not use `itertools.combinations` ? -- Also for the lengths, nested for loops should work `for i in range(len(letters)): for li in range(i):`

Comment: I am trying to create a list of every combination of the array (up to any length) and the relevant number. This list is then passed through another loop for a regression model.

Comment: I edited your code to add line wrapping (and parentheses to allow that) to make it easier to see the repetition here

Comment: What should happen if `len(letters) == 0`?

Comment: Thanks for line wrapping the code Eric. To answer your question, the code wouldn't run is len(letters) == 0. There is additional functionality prior to this section which checks the arrays length and the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this?

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

#variable length
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

n = len(letters) # Max limit for each element, ie. limit of 2 from [a, b], for k = 2 is ['a00 b00', 'a00 b10', 'a10 b00', 'a10 b10']
k = 3 # Number of elements we want to pick.
variable_s = []

#run loop based on array length.
for x, p in enumerate(itertools.product(range(n), repeat=k)):
    variable_s.append(' '.join([letter + str(q).zfill(2)[::-1]
                        for letter, q in zip(letters, p)]))
```

Comment: `letters[:len(letters)], p[:]` is better spelt `letters, p`

Comment: The output I got from changing out the if statement with what you gave was ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53']. I have updated the question with the output I am looking for.

Comment: I've edit the answer as well. Btw. for me it works just fine. For `k = 3`, and `n = 7` i got `['a00 b00 c00',
 'a00 b00 c10',
 'a00 b00 c20',
 'a00 b00 c30'..,` There is also no need for knowing the number of combinations beforehand. Just change `variable_s[x]` to `variable_s.append()` and its fine.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, the output of your answer I would expect would be ['a00 b00 c00 d00 e00 f00 g00', 'a00 b00 c00 d00 e00 f00 g10',  'a00 b00 c00 d00 e00 f00 g20',... etc,], whereas I got ['a00 b00 c00',
 'a00 b00 c10',
 'a00 b00 c20',
 'a00 b00 c30',
 'a00 b00 c40',
 'a00 b00 c50',
 'a00 b00 c60',... etc.]

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is the ability for a user to be able to change only the values in letters(n) and increment (y) to get up to n^y different possible combinations. They need to be in a string to be passed through the statsmodels ols module.

Comment: So that's all u need. Just keep `n = len(letters)` which will allow you to get up to N quantities of each items, and change the `k` variable to whatever suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the smallest change you could make - replace your `if` statement with:

```
variable_s[x] = ''.join(
    letter+str(format(p_i/(increment)**(-1.0),'.2f')).replace("0.", "")
    for letter, p_i in zip(letters, p)
)
```

Other notes:

- `p[1]/(increment)**(-1.0)` is better spelt `p[1] * increment`
- `x=0; for p in itertools.product(range(d), repeat=e): x = x+1` is better spelt `x = d**e`

Comment: The output I got from changing out the if statement with what you gave was ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26']. I have updated the question with the output I am looking for.